# Bounce Mail Retention Policy in Civi

Tags: civimail, bounce

I have the problem, that a bounce mailbox I am using ran full, and it's kind of hard to monitor , since the joblog of CiviCRM needs to be watched (Bounce Mail Cronjob).

Since Civi is managing the mailbox anyways, and moves mails to CiviMail/processed and CiviMail/ignored, shouldn't CiviCRM clean up afterwards and delete old mails? Or shouldn't there be at least an option for that?

Maybe there is an extension implementing that, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We integrated that into an extension, found here at [github](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.mailingtools). Retention can be configured in days for each folder.

Extension is still alpha, handle with care.